# Using a list of file names from a CSV file to find and copy files using Python

Tags: python, csv

I need to use a list of file names from a CSV file to find and copy the respective files. Below is the code. I'm not getting any errors, but the following is not yielding any results (I have checked and rechecked the sample list I created with the appropriate files). Any idea where I messed up? I appreciate any and all help. (I'm using the latest version of Python)

```
import os, shutil, csv

files_to_find = []
with open('C:\\pdfsearch.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    files_to_find = list(reader)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\mail'):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            print ('Found file in: ') + str(root)
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), 'C:\\Matches')
```

Comment: what does your `files_to_find` list look like? does it have relative or absolute paths?

Comment: The csv only consists of two cells at the moment. The files_to_find list is being printed as [['1003055716CBR201510.pdf'], ['1003080516CBR201510.pdf']]

Comment: I think you want "for file_name in reader: files_to_find.append(file_name)".

Comment: or dont use csv reader ... I assume that the entries are split by row ... so just `set(open("pdfsearch.csv").read().splitlines(False))`

Comment: I replaced the "files_to_find=list(reader) with the above and still am not receiving any results.

Comment: @DavidCullen that is identical to what he has in terms of output

Comment: Then they want "for line in reader: files_to_find.append(line[0]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that csvreader returns rows so you end up with a list of lists ... so instead of the output you expect `['1003055716CBR201510.pdf', '1003080516CBR201510.pdf']` you get `[['1003055716CBR201510.pdf'], ['1003080516CBR201510.pdf']]`

just dont use csvreader

```
_files_to_find=set(open("pdfsearch.csv").read().splitlines(False))
```

or alternatively take the first element of each row

```
with open('C:\\pdfsearch.csv') as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        _files2find.append(row[0])
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Not using csvreader seemed to solve the problem.